# Add usage examples into swagger

Tags: python, flask, swagger, documentation, openapi

We're using swagger to document our API. We need to add some API usage examples. Not just how to call some endpoint, but what endpoint in which order the user need to call to achieve some goals. Something like usage scenarios.

Is it possible to add in Swagger? Or maybe there is some alternative that does that? We do need the API endpoints descriptions and a way to run the endpoints as in Swagger, so switching to mkdocs or something similar is not really feasible.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new workflow specification from the OAI: https://github.com/OAI/sig-workflows/blob/main/versions/1.0.0.md - it is very new but tooling support is coming very soon.

Comment: That looks nice, but "very soon" is a bit late for me :)